# How can i change column with dd--MON-yyyy format to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-date-functions

I have column name PERIODE with dd-MON-yyyy format and I want to change it to dd-mm-yyyy format,  already tried some function but the format didn't changed

Comment: Use [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: Follow the documentation. There's tons of examples!

Comment: What is the data type of the `periode` column?  If it is a sensible data type, `date` or one of the `timestamp` data types, it does not have a format.  And thus you cannot change the format.  You could write a query that returns a `varchar2` data type in a particular format.  If the column is a `varchar2` then you have the wrong data type.  You could convert the existing string to a date and then to another string in a different format but you really should fix the data model.

Comment: okay its make sense now thankyou for the answer :D

Comment: You can change the default _display_ format for any DATE column in SQL Developer. Might be easier than using to_date() in every query you run.

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
select to_char(v_date_type, 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual;
```